# Random point distribtion

Tags: probability, statistics

How to generate numerically a set of random points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2),\cdots, (x_N,y_N)$ such that the pair-wise distances

$d = \sqrt { (x_i-x_j)^2 + (y_i-y_j)^2}$, for all $ 0<i\le N, 0<j\le N $

satisfy some given distribution $P(d)$ (e.g., Gaussian, exponential, etc.).

Comment: Interesting question - where is it from?

Comment: Also note that the distribution of distances can never be Gaussian, since $d>0$ :)

Comment: If you want to exclude $i=j$ then it might be neater to write $1 \le i \lt j \le N$

Comment: The question is from mixing two components, e.g., fine particles in the air; stars distribution in the universe, etc. I distilled it into this general form. The question may not be well posed but to me it made some sense.

Comment: I think for this to work you need to have an infinite number of points, otherwise, imagine a point on the convex hull of your dataset vs one at the center of the "cloud", the distance distribution will be right skewed for the former and more symetric for the latter. I don't know if that can be corrected for finite samples. However, it seems like one could develop a method that asymptotically approaches some distribution...although as @Nathaniel said, you cannot specify d arbitrarily. Even without positivity, you need a distribution that exhibits conditional self-similarity.

Comment: Yes, the number of samples is usually large.

Comment: Is the desired distribution on $d$ a conditional density, e.g., $f(D_{ij}=d|(x_i,y_i))$? Or are you trying to specify the overall distribution of distances within the group of points, as opposed to about each point?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: no. it's not conditional. It's the distribution of all pairwise distances.

Answer (score 1):

If you sample all Points independently from a fixed spatial Distribution with density $g:\mathbb R^2 \to [0,\infty)$ then every two distinct Points have the same distance Distribution. Now if $F$ is the cumulative density function of the Distribution $P(d)$, it will have to solve the following equation
$$ F(r) = \mathbb P(\|x_1-x_2\|_2 \leq r) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} \int_{B_r(x_1)} g(x_1) g(x_2) dx_2 dx_1  = \int_{\mathbb R^2} g(x) (g \ast \mathbf 1_{B_r})(x) dx.$$ 
Here $B_r(x)$ is the Ball around $x$ with radius $r$. Now this is some Kind of integral equation, which to solve numerically is another question in the numerics section.